# Is there anyway to merge two datasets that with two similar key column but not the same key column?

Tags: python, r, pandas, tidyverse

I have two datasets as follows:

a:

| have lunch | have dinner |
| --- | --- |
| set a | set 1 |
| set b | set 2 |
| ... | ... |

b:

| variable | variable_value | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| have lunch | set a | 0.2 |
| have lunch | set b | 0.5 |
| have dinner | set 1 | 1.5 |
| have dinner | set 2 | 1.7 |
| ... | ... | ... |

My expected outcome:

c:

| have lunch | have lunch value | have dinner | have dinner value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| set a | 0.2 | set 1 | 1.5 |
| set b | 0.5 | set 2 | 1.7 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

Is there anyway to merge these two datasets in python/r?

I can think of one solution in R:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
b %<>% pivot_wider(names_from = variable, values_from = value)

left_join(a,b)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt), [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), then [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
out = (a
  .melt(ignore_index=False, value_name='variable_value')
  .reset_index()
  .merge(b, how='left')
  .pivot(index='index', columns='variable')
)
```

Output:

```
         variable_value                  value           
variable    have dinner have lunch have dinner have lunch
index                                                    
0                 set 1      set a         1.5        0.2
1                 set 2      set b         1.7        0.5
```

For a formatting closer to what you have, further reprocess the column names:

```
out = (a.melt(ignore_index=False, value_name='variable_value')
  .reset_index()
  .merge(b, how='left')
  .pivot(index='index', columns='variable')
  .sort_index(level=1, axis=1)
  .rename_axis(index=None)
)

out.columns = out.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[1]}{" value" if x[0] == "variable_value" else ""}')
```

Output:

```
   have dinner have dinner value  have lunch have lunch value
0          1.5             set 1         0.2            set a
1          1.7             set 2         0.5            set b
```

##### alternative

Or, using a loop and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```py
out = pd.concat([a[[col]].merge(b.loc[b['variable'].eq(col),
                                      ['variable_value', 'value']]
                                 .rename(columns={'variable_value': col,
                                                  'value': f'{col} value'
                                                 }),
                               how='left'
                               )
                 for col in a], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  have lunch  have lunch value have dinner  have dinner value
0      set a               0.2       set 1                1.5
1      set b               0.5       set 2                1.7
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'exact formatting'? P.S. I didn't downvote your answer.

Comment: I meant to have `xx`/`xx value` in place of a MultiIndex like in my first step.

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
lunch = b[b['variable']=='have lunch'][['variable_value',   'value']]
dinner = b[b['variable']=='have dinner'][['variable_value', 'value']]

c = a.merge(lunch ,left_on='have lunch', right_on='variable_value', how='left').merge(
dinner,left_on='have dinner', right_on='variable_value', how='left')[
['have lunch', 'variable_value_x', 'have dinner', 'variable_value_y']].set_axis(
['have lunch', 'have lunch value', 'have dinner', 'have dinner value'], axis=1)
print(c)
```

Output:

```
   have lunch   have lunch value    have dinner have dinnervalue
0   set a          set a               set 1        set 1
1   set b          set b               set2         set2
```

Comment: Appreciate your effort but I have about 50+ categories in `variables` so your methods may be too cumbersome...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll keep that in mind when writing future responses.